# How to bind label to Google Map within a Form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub FormView1_DataBinding(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBinding

    Dim streetAddres As String = Nothing
    Dim EventLabel As Label = FindControl("Event_locationLabel")
    Dim findMap As GMap = FindControl("GMap1")

    Dim GeoCode As GeoCode = Nothing
    ' Get user typed text from text box
    streetAddres = EventLabel.Text
    ' pass your city name in the geo code request it return geo code
    GeoCode = findMap.getGeoCodeRequest(streetAddres)
    ' Add the geocode in
    Dim gLatLng As New GLatLng(GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lat, GeoCode.Placemark.coordinates.lng)
    ' Set center of map based on latitude and longitude coordinates
    findMap.setCenter(gLatLng, 16, GMapType.GTypes.Physical)
    Dim oMarker As New GMarker(gLatLng)
    ' Bind that marker data in google map
    findMap.addGMarker(oMarker)

End Sub
```

**ERROR:**

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Debugged: stopped in the line: `streetAddres = EventLabel.Text`

Comment: EventLabel not exist reference of Event_locationLabel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Event_locationLabel` is not a valid control id. You will need to examine the page to see what it should be called.

If access to the page source is blocked for some reason, you can open internet explorer and hit F12 to access the developer tools. These are very handy for identifying (and adjusting) elements in a page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My Event_LocationLabel is a label taken from my database and is an address. I'm trying to load the googlemap from the label address in a FormView

Comment: How does the label get added to the page? You are trying to find the control in the page and it is not there, so this could be an issue with where you are adding the control or where you are trying to access it.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Event_locationLabel" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Event_location") %>' />

I placed in the aspx with in a formview. THe first post code is the backcode.

thank you once again

Comment: Ok, is this control in a content control (panel, tab, group box, user control) or master page? In many of these cases, the ID actually rendered to the client is altered to qualify it by the container control. For example, I have controls that are rendered as tabEd__ctl0_uc1_txtField. The control id in the user control is txtField, but it is embedded in a tab, which adds some of the prefix information. This is why it's helpful to view the page source as it is rendered in order to see what the actual ID is.

Comment: this is not a masterpage. it is a noraml aspx page. thank you